# Linking against older symbol version in a .so file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

Using gcc and ld on x86_64 linux I need to link against a newer version of a library (glibc 2.14) but the executable needs to run on a system with an older version (2.5). Since the only incompatible symbol is memcpy (needing memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 but the library providing memcpy@GLIBC_2.14), I would like to tell the linker that instead of taking the default version for memcpy, it should take an old version I specify.

I found a quite arkward way to do it: simply specify a copy of the old .so file at the linker command line. This works fine, but I don't like the idea of having multiple .so files (I could only make it work by specifying all old libraries I link to that also have references to memcpy) checked into the svn and needed by my build system.

So I am searching for a way to tell the linker to take the old versioned symbol.

Alternatives that don't work (well) for me are:

- Using asm .symver (as seen on [Web Archive of Trevor Pounds' Blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20160107032111/http://www.trevorpounds.com/blog/?p=103)) since this would require me to make sure the symver is before all the code that is using memcpy, which would be very hard (complex codebase with 3rd party code)
- Maintaining a build environment with the old libraries; simply because I want to develop on my desktop system and it would be a pita to sync stuff around in our network.

When thinking about all the jobs a linker does, it doesn't seem like a hard thing to imlpement, after all it has some code to figure out the default version of a symbol too.

Any other ideas that are on the same complexity level as a simple linker command line (like creating a simple linker script etc.) are welcome too, as long as they are not weird hacks like editing the resulting binary...

**edit:**
To conserve this for the future readers, additionally to the below ideas I found the option `--wrap` to the linker, which might be useful sometimes too.

Comment: You know, memcpy( ) hasn't changed in thirty years. You might want to mention why you need this. (I apologize for asking why; I hate when folks do that. But you must have a real, imperative reason that might be crucial to know, given that memcpy() has been so stable for so long.) Thanks!

Comment: @PeteWilson: Simply because when I build my program against glibc 2.14 it won't run on a system with an older glibc, since those don't provide the versioned symbol memcpy@GLIBC_2.14

Comment: @PeteWilson My answer links a bug report explaining memcpy issue, in terms of what actually changed - glibc made a change that breaks code that relied on the (technically undefined in overlapping cases) undocumented "always iterate from left to right" behavior of traditional unix memcpy implementations. More relevant to the issue here, though is the fact that the old version is obviously the only one provided in earlier versions of glibc which he has to support.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39537664/1546337

Comment: This reads plausible: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-11/msg00303.html

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb how so? Symbol versioning exists for this very purpose. So if I decide that the older version with its old semantics suits me, why not be able to link against that? Of all the many symbols in glibc only `realpath` and `memcpy` ever stood out and required correction. And there is no real problem reading up in the change log, diffing source code and finding that the older version does what one expects of it ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just link memcpy statically - pull memcpy.o out of libc.a `ar x /path/to/libc.a memcpy.o` (whatever version - memcpy is pretty much a standalone function) and include it in your final link. Note that static linking may complicate licensing issues if your project is distributed to the public and not open-source.

Alternatively, you could simply implement memcpy yourself, though the hand-tuned assembly version in glibc is likely to be more efficient

Note that [memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691336) is mapped to memmove (old versions of memcpy consistently copied in a predictable direction, which led to it sometimes being misused when memmove should have been used), and this is the only reason for the version bump - you could simply replace memcpy with memmove in your code for this specific case.

Or you could go to static linking, or you could ensure that all systems on your network have the same or better version than your build machine.

Comment: I will be discussing the idea of providing a memcpy.o with my coworkers tomorrow, but the advantage of being able to tell the linker the version would probably be to not have to do the same for when for later versions other things change. As for the second part, as I mentioned, the code base is complex and contains 3rd party code, so unfortunately replacing memmove by memcpy is not viable (in fact about 95% of the memcpy calls are from 3rd party code)

Comment: Well, the best solution in the long run is to make sure the build machine (i.e. your desktop machine) has the lowest common denominator of library version - either by maintaining a separate build environment or by upgrading everyone else.

Comment: +1 for mentioning memmove( ); imo there's no good reason for using memcpy( ) with its stupid restriction on overlapping strings.

Comment: @Random832: This is the common struggle between administration and development. I want to be on recent versions and can't work with the ancient stuff that the system on the server provides, and they want to keep stable for a decade :/

Comment: You should only replace memcpy() with memmove() on x86_64, not other architectures that have not versioned memcpy(), and therefore won't bump the dependency. Do not sacrifice performance needlessly. (and make sure to test with memcpy())

Comment: @PeteWilson: memmove has two extra potential pipeline bubbles from the overlap check and I don't think it can be inlined away for known sizes like memcpy.

Comment: The reason for the bump up is not related to memmove. In 2.14 memcpy became a GNU_IFUNC. That is a function which returns a function pointer, which then is executed. This adds one level of indirection, which is exploited when loading the program by initializing these function pointers to the version of the function optimized for the host CPU. This means that if you link against compiled code which expect memcpy to behave as an IFunc, there will be problems.

Comment: This answer is not useful to visitors looking to solve the actual problem of binding to older symbols.  Pulling object files out of libc for static linking is not a good technical solution in most circumstances and is illegal if the application is proprietary.

Answer (score 52):

I found the following working solution. First create file memcpy.c:

```
#include <string.h>

/* some systems do not have newest memcpy@@GLIBC_2.14 - stay with old good one */
asm (".symver memcpy, memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");

void *__wrap_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    return memcpy(dest, src, n);
}
```

No additional CFLAGS needed to compile this file. Then link your program with **-Wl,--wrap=memcpy**.

Comment: This didn't work for me for some reason.  Still looks for the old memcpy

Comment: Ortwin Angermeier's answer did not work for me, but to my surprise - this worked perfectly, and the glibc 2.14 dependency was dropped like a bad habit. Thank you!

Comment: This works because the interface to `memcpy` does not change. In the general case, we need not just the old symbols, but also the old header files. Like cases in which structure members change, so the old version of the function expects an old structure.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're compiling on an architecture that wasn't built back in 2002 when x86-64 was first added - you'll get an error that the requested versioned symbols are not available. You need something like `#if defined(__x86_64__) && !defined(__ILP32__) && defined(__GNU_LIBRARY__)` to guard against this (`__ILP32__` is for [x32 ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X32_ABI) which was introduced in 2012).

Comment: I had trouble with dlsym() building a lib under gcc 9.4 / ld 2.34 that has to link on a variety of older and newer systems, where ld barfs up error messages for asm(".symver dlsym, dlsym@GLIBC_2.2.5") (documented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118615/linking-to-so-with-newer-symbol). I got it to work by using a version script of GLIBC_2.2.5{dlsym;}; instead. Building the lib on other systems from 4.6 to 11.3 and various ld versions seems to work fine with either method

Comment: MaskRay's blog at https://maskray.me/blog/2020-11-26-all-about-symbol-versioning is helpful in understanding symbol versioning, for example combining version scripts

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. A third party library we use needs the old `memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5`. My solution is an extended approach @anight posted.

I also warp the `memcpy` command, but i had to use a slightly different approach, since the solution @anight posted did not work for me.

**memcpy_wrap.c:**

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

asm (".symver wrap_memcpy, memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");
void *wrap_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n) {
  return memcpy(dest, src, n);
}
```

**memcpy_wrap.map:**

```
GLIBC_2.2.5 {
   memcpy;
};
```

**Build the wrapper:**

```
gcc -c memcpy_wrap.c -o memcpy_wrap.o
```

Now finally when linking the program add

- `-Wl,--version-script memcpy_wrap.map`
- `memcpy_wrap.o`

so that you will end up with something like:

```
g++ <some flags> -Wl,--version-script memcpy_wrap.map <some .o files> memcpy_wrap.o <some libs>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem. Trying to install some oracle components on RHEL 7.1, I got this:

```
$ gcc -o /some/oracle/bin/foo .... -L/some/oracle/lib ... 
/some/oracle/lib/libfoo.so: undefined reference to `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'
```

It seems that (my) RHEL's glibc only defines memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5:

```
$ readelf -Ws /usr/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux6E/lib64/libc_real.so | fgrep memcpy@
   367: 000000000001bfe0    16 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 memcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
  1166: 0000000000019250    16 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 wmemcpy@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

So, I managed to get around this, by first creating a memcpy.c file without wrapping, as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
asm (".symver old_memcpy, memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");       // hook old_memcpy as memcpy@2.2.5
void *old_memcpy(void *, const void *, size_t );
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)   // then export memcpy
{
    return old_memcpy(dest, src, n);
}
```

and a memcpy.map file that exports our memcpy as memcpy@GLIBC_2.14:

```
GLIBC_2.14 {
   memcpy;
};
```

I then compiled my own memcpy.c into a shared lib like this:

```
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -c memcpy.c
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -Wl,--version-script memcpy.map -o libmemcpy-2.14.so memcpy.o -lc
```

, moved libmemcpy-2.14.so into /some/oracle/lib (pointed to by -L arguments in my linking), and linked again by

```
$ gcc -o /some/oracle/bin/foo .... -L/some/oracle/lib ... /some/oracle/lib/libmemcpy-2.14.so -lfoo ...
```

(which compiled without errors) and verified it by:

```
$ ldd /some/oracle/bin/foo
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9f3fe000)
    /some/oracle/lib/libmemcpy-2.14.so (0x00007f963a63e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f963a428000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f963a20c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f963a003000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9639c42000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f963aa5b000)
```

This worked for me. I hope it does it for you, too.

Answer (score 5):

I'm clearly a little late responding to this but I recently upgraded (more reasons to never upgrade) my Linux OS to XUbuntu 14.04 which came with the new libc.  I compile a shared library on my machine which is used by clients who, for whatever legitimate reasons, have not upgraded their environment from 10.04.  The shared library I compiled no longer loaded in their environment because gcc put a dependency on memcpy glibc v. 2.14 (or higher).  Let's leave aside the insanity of this.  The workaround across my whole project was three fold:

1. added to my gcc cflags: -include glibc_version_nightmare.h
2. created the glibc_version_nightmare.h
3. created a perl script to verify the symbols in the .so

glibc_version_nightmare.h:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__LP64__)  /* only under 64 bit gcc */
#include <features.h>       /* for glibc version */
#if defined(__GLIBC__) && (__GLIBC__ == 2) && (__GLIBC_MINOR__ >= 14)
/* force mempcy to be from earlier compatible system */
__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");
#endif
#undef _FEATURES_H      /* so gets reloaded if necessary */
#endif
```

perl script fragment:

```
...
open SYMS, "nm $flags $libname |";

my $status = 0;

sub complain {
my ($symbol, $verstr) = @_;
print STDERR "ERROR: $libname $symbol requires $verstr\n";
$status = 1;
}

while (<SYMS>) {
next unless /\@\@GLIBC/;
chomp;
my ($symbol, $verstr) = (m/^\s+.\s(.*)\@\@GLIBC_(.*)/);
die "unable to parse version from $libname in $_\n"
    unless $verstr;
my @ver = split(/\./, $verstr);
complain $symbol, $verstr
    if ($ver[0] > 2 || $ver[1] > 10);
}
close SYMS;

exit $status;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Minimal runnable self contained example**

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/81ab30c55634db24216e89ada1e0f271cac074e7/shared-library/symbol-version).

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "a.h"

#if defined(V1)
__asm__(".symver a,a@LIBA_1");
#elif defined(V2)
__asm__(".symver a,a@LIBA_2");
#endif

int main(void) {
#if defined(V1)
    assert(a() == 1);
#else
    assert(a() == 2);
#endif
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

a.c

```
#include "a.h"

__asm__(".symver a1,a@LIBA_1");
int a1(void) {
    return 1;
}

/* @@ means "default version". */
__asm__(".symver a2,a@@LIBA_2");
int a2(void) {
    return 2;
}
```

a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

int a(void);

#endif
```

a.map

```
LIBA_1{
    global:
    a;
    local:
    *;
};

LIBA_2{
    global:
    a;
    local:
    *;
};
```

Makefile

```
CC := gcc -pedantic-errors -std=c89 -Wall -Wextra

.PHONY: all clean run

all: main.out main1.out main2.out

run: all
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main.out
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main1.out
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main2.out

main.out: main.c libcirosantilli_a.so
    $(CC) -L'.' main.c -o '$@' -lcirosantilli_a

main1.out: main.c libcirosantilli_a.so
    $(CC) -DV1 -L'.' main.c -o '$@' -lcirosantilli_a

main2.out: main.c libcirosantilli_a.so
    $(CC) -DV2 -L'.' main.c -o '$@' -lcirosantilli_a

a.o: a.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c '$<' -o '$@'

libcirosantilli_a.so: a.o
    $(CC) -Wl,--version-script,a.map -L'.' -shared a.o -o '$@'

libcirosantilli_a.o: a.c
    $(CC) -fPIC -c '$<' -o '$@'

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.a *.so *.out
```

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

This workaround seem not compatible with -flto compile option.

My solution is calling memmove. memove does exactly the same jobs than memcpy.
The only difference is when src and dest zone overlap, memmove is safe and memcpy is unpredictable. So we can safely always call memmove instead memcpy

```
#include <string.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void *__wrap_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
    {
        return memmove(dest, src, n);
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

For nim-lang, I elaborated on a solution I found using the C compiler `--include=` flag as follows:

Create a file **symver.h** with:

```
__asm__(".symver fcntl,fcntl@GLIBC_2.4");
```

Build your program with `nim c ---passC:--include=symver.h`

As for me I'm cross compiling too. I compile with `nim c --cpu:arm --os:linux --passC:--include=symver.h ...` and I can get symbol versions using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -T ../arm-libc.so.6 | grep fcntl`

I had to remove `~/.cache/nim` at some point. And it seems to work.

Comment: This works, but has the downside that if you already have an existing shared object (say libstdc++.so) which links against newer symbols, the linker will still error out on those. This trick only ever works on the code you really _compile_ yourself. And yes, this implies that one _could_ rebuild `libstdc++` from source, using something like the above header file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get away with making a simple C file containing the symver statement and perhaps a dummy function calling memcpy. Then you just have to ensure that the resulting object file is the first file given to linker.

Comment: That would be nice, but is unfortunately not the case. Inspecting files with nm, it seems that for every mention (as U) of "memcpy" it takes "memcpy@GLIBC_2.14" and only for the explicit mentions of memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5 it takes that one. The final executable has two undefined entries, one for 2.14 and one for 2.2.5. Nothing changes when I place the dummy file at a different position in the linker line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you either link memcpy() statically; or find the source of memcpy( ) and compile it as your own library.

Comment: That might have license issues since glibc is released under GPL.

Comment: Use the version from musl-libc in such a case, gets rid of the licensing issue (as it's under a very liberal license with parts in the public domain) and is quite portable.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue, but instead of one older GLIBC symbol, we have to provide in our .so libs a mix of newer ones with necessary functionality and older ones our libs may be referencing but are not available. This situation occurs because we are shipping to customers high performance codec libs with vectorized math functions and we cannot impose requirements on what version of OS distro, gcc, or glibc they use. As long as their machine has appropriate SSE and AVX extensions, the libs should work. Here is what we did:

1. Include glibc 2.35 libmvec.so.1 and libm.so.6 files in a separate subfolder. These contain the necessary vectorized math functions. In a "hello codec" application example, we reference these in the link target depending on what distro, gcc, and glibc versions are found by the Makefile. More or less, for anything with glibc v2.35 or higher the high performance libs are referenced, otherwise slower libs are referenced.
2. To deal with missing symbols -- the subject of this thread -- we used a modification of [Ortwin Anermeier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540286/ortwin-angermeier)'s solution, in turn based on [anight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1149316/anight)'s solution, but without using the -Wl,--wrap=xxx option.

The .map file looks like:

```
GLIBC_2.35 {
   hypot;
   :
   : (more function symbols as needed)
};

GLIBC_2.32 {
   exp10;
   :
   :  (more function symbols as needed)
};

 :
 : (more version nodes as needed)
```

and in a "stublib" .so we have:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <math.h>

asm(".symver hypot_235, hypot@GLIBC_2.35");
asm(".symver exp10_232, exp10f@GLIBC_2.32");
/* ... more as needed */

double hypot_235(double x, double y) { return hypot(x, y); }
double exp10_232(double x) { return exp10(x); }
/* ... more as needed */
```

3. -lstublib.so is then included in the app build *as the last link item*, even after -lm.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261220/link-errors-with-ffast-math-ffinite-math-only-and-glibc-2-31) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70889603/glibc-versioned-symbol-and-undefined-reference-to-memcpyglibc-2-14) also offer clues, but they not handling the general case of a .so flexible enough to be used on a wide variety of systems.

Comment: For reference and searching, the newer vectorized math functions have symbols such as _ZGVbN4v_acosf, _ZGVbN2vv_atan2, etc. There is a long list of these depending on SSE and AVX version, for example in the ABI list at https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/libmvec.abilist

Answer (score 0):

It may caused by old ld (gnu link) version.
For following simple problem:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char buf[5];
    memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf));
    printf("ok\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I use ld 2.19.1, memset is relocated to: memset@@GLIBC_2.0, and cause crash.
After upgraded to 2.25, it is: memset@plt, and crash solved.