# How can I build a shared library that will be used for different g++ version?

Tags: g++, version, shared, glibc

I want to compile a shared library to other developers, but without shipping source code. 
The .so file I built against g++ 4.6, but they used g++ 4.4. 
When they linked with my .so file, g++ reported: undefined reference to 'memcpy@GLIBC_2.14'.

I think there are two possible solutions:

1. I rebuild my shared library which do not depends on specified GLIBC version.
2. Tell them a simple way to link with my shared library with some compiler options to make it work.

I have no idea in both methods, how can I achieve these solutions or one of them?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I found a link flag: -static-libgcc

Does that help if I build my shared library with this option? Any drawback?

Comment: You're thinking of **glibc**, not **glib** - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823267/linking-against-older-symbol-version-in-a-so-file).

Comment: It's not the g++ version, it's the libc version. I only have `memcpy@GLIBC_2.0` on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, so I would get the undefined reference too. Link against the oldest glibc you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I add these options to make it without depends on any shared libraries.

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -nodefaultlibs -shared -fPIC
```

The ldd reports 'static linked', and no any required .so files.

This might be useful for anyone who want to ship portable shared library.

Comment: I have extreme doubts about the correctness of what you're doing here.

Answer (score 4):

That symbol is defined by glibc (the C library) not by GCC, so `-static-libgcc` won't help in the slightest because it only affects `libgcc` not `libc`.

You can force the compiler and linker to use the old `memcpy` symbol like this (I'm assuming you're compiling on x86_64, so the older glibc they're using probably only has `memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5`, if you're on x86 then you might want `memcpy@GLIBC_2.0` instead):

```
__asm__(".symver memcpy,memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5");
memcpy(tgt, src, n);
```

The [`.symver` directive](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html) causes any references to `memcpy` to bind to the symbol `memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5` instead of the default, which is `memcpy@GLIBC_2.14` in your case.