# overridding glibc function in shared library to downgrade glibc required version in cross compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, build, glibc, ldd

I have a C++ 3rd party library in source code. It is self-contained and does not refer to any other library. It uses C++14, hence it requires a modern gcc compiler.

I want to use some of its functions in a software application compiled for RHEL5  with an old version of gcc, which does not understand modern C++.

To solve the problem I am creating with gcc 7.2 a shared library (.so) which exposes a plain and simple C api. I would like the `so` file to be self contained hence I use the link line:

`g++ -shared -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc`

I am not using the option `-static`, as I could not get it to work, despite I used `-fPIC` when generating my object files. Probably because the static libraries for `libstdc++` might be compiled without `fPIC`. So `ldd` shows that my `so` has some dependencies on `libc` and `libm`. `objectdump -T` shows that most of these dependencies are compatible with RHEL5, because they require a version of `GLIBC` older than 2.5. However there is one dependency on `memcpy` which requires `GLIBC` 2.14. This does not come directly from my source code, but probably from `libstdc++` or `libgcc`, which are being statically linked.

Is there any way I can provide my own implementation of `memcpy` and tell the linker to use that everywhere, instead of the one from `glibc`?

Comment: Try to search for "gcc mocking call", something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961774/gnu-gcc-ld-wrapping-a-call-to-symbol-with-caller-and-callee-defined-in-the-sam

Comment: Found some good suggestions here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823267/linking-against-older-symbol-version-in-a-so-file/8823419#8823419  I just need to be careful with the fact that in 2.14 memcpy became a GNU_IFUNC function, therefore my local copy needs to have a consistent type, otherwise I may have a problem with libstdc++ and libgcc.