# Undefined symbol __pow_finite in GLIBC>=2.31

Tags: python, gcc, shared-libraries, cython, python-wheel

I'm trying to build and distribute an abandoned [package](https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python). I made a [fork](https://github.com/bitextor/bicleaner-ai-glove). Building it with [cibuildwheel](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel) instead on each machine will make thinks much more easier, but it's giving me a lot of issues. I successfully ran the building procedure in cibuildwheel of `py3{7,8,9,10}-manylinux_x86_64` (`manulinux2014` which has Glibc 2.17) and the test are running successfully in the docker image for all the python versions compiled. It also runs well on the machine I built it, outside the docker, which is Ubuntu 18.04 python 3.8. But when I install it in another machine (Fedora 36 Python 3.10 GLibc 2.36), one of the compiled binaries of the pyx extensions gives me this error:

```py
Traceback:
/usr/lib64/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_glove.py:4: in <module>
    from glove import Corpus, Glove
../venv-glove/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/glove/__init__.py:2: in <module>
    from .glove import Glove
../venv-glove/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/glove/glove.py:16: in <module>
    from .glove_cython import fit_vectors, transform_paragraph
E   ImportError: /home/user/venv-glove/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/glove/glove_cython.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: __pow_finite
```

At the Fedora machine, the local build of the wheel with `python setup.py wheel` works well.

After some search [here](https://github.com/google/filament/issues/2146) and [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/182), I found that it is related with the `-ffast-math` option. Disabling it avoids the issue but the performance is dropping a lot. Also adding `-fno-builtin` does not solve the issue.

Then I asked at cibuildwheel issue tracker [here](https://github.com/pypa/cibuildwheel/issues/1225) and they helped me to make it run defining the operator in the .c generated by Cython (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63261220/link-errors-with-ffast-math-ffinite-math-only-and-glibc-2-31)). After compiling with that and without specific `-march` parameter I'm able to run the code but it ends in an infinite loop. The function that runs indefinitely is [this one](https://github.com/bitextor/bicleaner-ai-glove/blob/9d463ff29275743e8dbc0cf8c6d8bb364cc7c746/glove/glove_cython.pyx#L20).

It seems that I'm facing the deprecation problem building with Glibc under 2.31 and using it in a system that has a higher version. I wonder if anyone here knows how to properly define the operators or if it's possible to compile the extensions without having to remove `-ffast-math`.

I also tried to debug the test that is failing with `gdb -ex r --args $(pyenv which python) -m pytest .` but the debugger can't catch the cython packages:

```
ImportError while importing test module '/home/user/work/glove/glove-python/tests/test_corpus.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/test_corpus.py:9: in <module>
    from glove import Corpus
glove/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from .corpus import Corpus
glove/corpus.py:10: in <module>
    from .corpus_cython import construct_cooccurrence_matrix
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glove.corpus_cython'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot load \_\_log\_finite from libm.so.6 with ctypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72363848/cannot-load-log-finite-from-libm-so-6-with-ctypes)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to link your library against libm?

Comment: Do you mean adding `-lm`? Yes I tried