# Linking to .so with newer symbol

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, glibc

I have libs that build with gcc 11.3 and 9.4 to take advantage of AVX optimizations, but they must link with run-times built under 4.6 and up. They call dlsym(), grepping objdump on either libdl.so.2 or libc.so.6 shows GLIBC_2.34 and GLIBC_2.2.5 dlsym symbols. Per the discussion at [Linking against an old version of libc to provide greater application coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032373/linking-against-an-old-version-of-libc-to-provide-greater-application-coverage/20065096), I add to the lib:

`asm(".symver dlsym, dlsym@GLIBC_2.2.5");`

to force the older, likely symbol on a wide range of run-time systems. This builds fine under 11.3 (ld 2.38), but 9.4 (2.34) produces:

no symbol version section for versioned symbol `dlsym@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Thinking that this might be something 9.4 and earlier, I tried gcc 4.6 (ld 2.22) and that builds fine. I also tried 11.2 (ld 2.34) which builds ok. On the 9.4 system I can verify the symbol is available in libdl using:

objdump -T /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 | grep -w dlsym

which shows:

00000000000014b0 g    DF .text  00000000000000c1  GLIBC_2.2.5 dlsym

is there a link option or other way to avoid this ? Or perhaps a better approach that supersedes the aforementioned stackoverflow thread or others along the same lines (e.g. [Linking against older symbol version in a .so file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823267/linking-against-older-symbol-version-in-a-so-file))

Comment: None of this has anything to do with your gcc version. `dlsym` is a part of glibc. You need a certain glibc version.

Comment: Create a 'devel system' that has same libs as the production system, and install the desired version of gcc from source on it. (Mind you, libgcc_s and libstdc++.so are compiler-version-specific.) Off: symbol-versioning was meant to solve some compatibility problems. It's a drawback that it creates bigger compatibility problems than it solves.

Comment: I got it to work on gcc 9.4 by not using .symver and instead using a version script of GLIBC_2.2.5{dlsym;};  Now when using the lib on systems with other gcc and ld versions, it links and runs fine . For a simple/mature function like dlsym, I don't see any compatibility issues. In this case it's not used often and is not performance sensitive. At some point I plan to test gcc 9.x before and after 9.4 to see what happens. MaskRay's blog at https://maskray.me/blog/2020-11-26-all-about-symbol-versioning is super helpful in understanding symbol versioning, for example combining version scripts