Why am I not able to link to a specific WEAK symbol version when compiling and linking a shared object?
I am in the process of building a shared object which needs to link to a function exported from another shared object (namely libstdc++). This function is exported as WEAK and has also a default version (func@@V1).
When I build an executable I can use the gcc asm directive to forcefully link to that specific V1 version, i.e.
__asm__(".symver func,func@V1")
And the executable not only builds fine and looking as the symbols with readelf -Wa I can see it's requiring func@V1.
If instead I try to build the same code as a shared object (with flags -fPIC and -shared), I get the following error:
No symbol version section for versioned symbol func@V1
If I then remove the __asm__ symver directive I can link the shared object, but the linkage to func is unversioned (i.e. looking at the shared object with readelf -Wa I can see a reference to func but not func@V1).
Why is it?
Is there a way to have the shared object link to a versioned WEAK symbol?
Thanks
Ps. The function is a C++ function exported by libstdc++.so.6, but I wanted to keep the example simple to understand

Looks like this is another instance of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78118615/linking-to-so-with-newer-symbol?noredirect=1#comment139042564_78118615 - perhaps I got hit by a similar bug, using gcc 4.9.3
